How to insert most recent data
Like many of you did before, I'm trying to rewrite a .NET application to use SqlBulkCopy to gain the needed performance profit when writing data to the database.
I understand SqlBulkCopy can only perform inserts and if I want to use updates as well, I'm going to need a staging table and merge the table to the permanent table. I've used MERGE in SQL before, so I guess I can figure this out.
I've seen examples using a transaction to make it extra safe...but when do you clean the staging table? Right after the MERGE statement? Something like DELETE IF EXISTS?
But what I don't understand: how does the MERGE statement know which record to merge? (assuming the transaction could fail and leave records untreated)
Example:



ID
Name
Surname
City




1
Bart
Simpson
Springfield


1
Bort
Simpson
Springfield


2
Lisa
Sampson
Springfield


2
Lisa
Simpson
Springfield


3
Homer
Simpson
Springfield



I understand you can never merge this as you don't know which records is preferred. In my case the most recent one, so I add could an extra column LastUpdatedOn that holds a timestamp as the name suspects.
But how can I tell MERGE to use the most recent row and delete the others to prevent an overwriting by older data the next run?
Or is there an other way, easier way to do this? Am I overlooking something?

hm, in my preview my table looks allright but when posting it's not working...must be missing something :-(

You need a unique column or columns in the ON clause that will uniquely identify a join to an existing row. You also need to DISTINCT over the staging table before you start.

You create and drop/truncate the table before doing your job. If you then have duplicates, why not only add the latest when you bulk insert them already

"must be missing something" You need a line break before and after a markdown table; [so] implemented different solutions for the preview and post rendering for markdown, and as the solutions are different, they result in different [[meta-tag:status-bydesign]] behaviour.

What about using a temporal table for bulk coping the data instead of a staging permanent table? All you need is updating/inserting some bunch of data after all.
